# Using enums in Swift

Tags: swift, enums, swift5

I am new to swift, after programming years with Objective-C.

I declare this on a file

```
  public enum Identifier {
    case car, boat, toy, water
  }
```

From another class I do:

```
var type : Identifier = Identifier.car
```

> ERROR: Use of undeclared Identifier

I also tried

```
class MyTypes {
  enum Identifier {
    case car, boat, toy, water
  }
}
```

and then

```
var type : MyTypes = MyTypes.Identifier.car
```

How do I use that?

Comment: The declaration is correct.

Comment: unbelievable. The file was not included on the target. I live Xcode. Please make that comment an answer, so I can accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible sources of the problem include that the file hasn’t been saved yet or that the file hasn’t been included in your Xcode project’s target. It would appear that the latter issue is the problem here.

---

By the way, your second example, defined within `MyTypes`, should be declared as follows:

```
var type: MyTypes.Identifier = .car
```

Or as:

```
var type = MyTypes.Identifier.car
```

Comment: No worries. You’ll undoubtedly get sufficient rep soon enough. Lol.